# time lag between text and background for slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery slideToggle for creating a left navigation. But problem is when ever I show the hidden content the background is sliding down slowly and the text is coming up faster. So the text appears on top of other content for  a few seconds.

The demo and code in attached [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/3dt3mdy7/) link

```
$(document).on("click", ".has-subitem", function () {
     $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle();
     $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down");
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

simple way to use overflow in css

```
.navi-list-multi-tabs > li {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks that works. but there is a problem in using it. I have a <span class="navi-current"></span> which is a pointer triangle to show the active link, this is to be shown outside the content. If I use overflow in css this will not appear :(

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam why you use  overflow: visible !important; in .submenu css?? if its not important just remove that line

Comment: by default when I hide and show the submenu class it adds display:block and overflow:hidden , so this makes my pointer on right side not to be shown. so I have to add overflow :visible to make it visible

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam  see that http://jsfiddle.net/3dt3mdy7/1/  I just target li inside .submenu  instead of .submenu

Comment: thanks a lot.. It works but I had to add overflow:visible for .submenu > li .. so I get text overlapping.. but not lag before... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

keep your content in div and then slide that div, I.e. $('div#id').slideToggle();

Answer (score 0):

Simple. I guess this might work.

```
$(document).on("click", ".has-subitem", function () {
     $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle().parents('.has-subitem').find('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down");
});
```

Because, jQuery does not wait for any actions to be completed except it is followed by the next action or its in ajax.